# How can I use a string in a loop to be used in a dataframe command? Using Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Say I have dataframe named `population` that contains the series `age` and `education`. I am interested in running the command `pd.qcut` so for example for `age` I would write `pd.qcut(population.age.values, [0, .25, .5, .75, 1],['a','b','c','d'])`.

I would like to do this for each column (and replace each column) in a loop form, as:

```
col_name = ['age', 'education']
for i in col_name:

   population.i=pd.qcut(population.i.values, [0, .25, .5, .75, 1],['a','b','c','d'])
```

But I cannot find the right function that opens the string for me in `population.i.values`. I tried `Poped(i)` but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `population[i]` instead of `population.i`.

The [pandas documentation about indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) explain how to access Series corresponding to *`colname`* by doing `frame[colname]`.

When you are doing `population.i` (called *Attribute Access* in the doc) pandas is looking for a columns who names actually `'i'`.

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly.